# Testing for a number within an array

Tags: javascript

The `.length` and values of the array however are randomly assigned. More specifically, `a()` randomly assigns `anArray.length` to a random value 1-3, and the values therein are also randomly assigned a value 1-3. I've coded `numTester()` to test for 2 within `anArray` after `a()` is executed.

```js
var anArray = [];
var numTester = function(aryParam, v) {

  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < aryParam.length; i++) {

    if (aryParam[i] == v) {

      return true;

    }

    return false;

  }

};
var a = function() {

  b = 0;

  c = setInterval(function() {

    b++;
    d = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
    anArray.push(d);

    if (b == d || b == 3) {

      clearInterval(c);
      document.write(anArray.join(", "), "<br />", numTester(anArray, 2));

    }

  }, 1);

};
a();
```

`numTester()` is supposed to return `true` if 2 is any of 1, 2, or 3 numbers within the array. The issue is that I've found that it will only return `true` if the first number of the array is 2. Why is this?

```js
var anArray = [];
var numTester = function(aryParam, v) {

    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < aryParam.length; i++) {

        if(aryParam[i] == v) {

            return true;

        }

        return false;

    }

};
var a = function() {

    b = 0;

    c = setInterval(function() {

        b++;
        d = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
        anArray.push(d);

        if(b == d || b == 3) {

            clearInterval(c);
            document.write(anArray.join(", ") + "<br />", numTester(anArray, 2));

        }

    }, 1);

};
a();
```

Comment: Looks like a use case for [*Array.prototype.some*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some): `anArray.some(x => x == v)`. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return false in the for loop, your loop will only ever iterate once, need to move it outside the for loop.

```
var numTester = function(aryParam, v) {

    var i;
    for(i = 0; i < aryParam.length; i++) {
        if(aryParam[i] == v) {
            return true;
        }

        return false; <-- remove this
    }
    return false; <-- put it here
}
```

Comment: jeez.  now I feel dumb lol.  That was actually quite obvious.  Thanks a lot Heinrich.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, have a good look at your `for` loop:

```
  for (i = 0; i < aryParam.length; i++) {

    if (aryParam[i] == v) {

      return true;

    }

    return false;

  }
```

The code in its body is:

```
if (aryParam[i] == v) {

  return true;

}

return false;
```

Which means it will either return `true` or `false` on its *first iteration*.

**The solution:**

Move the `return false` *out* of your loop:

```
  for (i = 0; i < aryParam.length; i++) {

    if (aryParam[i] == v) {

      return true;

    }


  }
  return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use [array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
var numTester = function(aryParam, v) {
  return aryParam.find((ar) => ar == v) && true || false;
};
```